# GLPI Follow Up Tag Email Notification faill

Tags: notifications, glpi

I'm trying to create a simple follow up notification template, but the ##followup.description## tag doesn't act as expected, just replicating the tag itself in the email. What could it be?

[notification template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qF5R.png)
[notification results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOB76.png)

Answer (score 0):

you need to put ##lang.followup.description## before ##followup.description##
##lang.xxx## tag for right translation of  tag, it uses system language.